# Instagram Like API. Posting a like through curl and php

Tags: api, curl, instagram

I am trying to figure out how to POST a like for Instagram. Click here to view my website for testing this API.

http://ewands.no-ip.biz/Intern/guangjian/instagram/

This is my first time trying the Instagram API. Google it but no tutorial is found on this topic. Below are my PHP code.

Getting the media id:

```
$api = file_get_contents("http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/n5DyHnKWoo");      
$apiObj = json_decode($api,true);      
$media_id = $apiObj['media_id'];
```

After the like button is clicked, the URL becomes http://ewands.no-ip.biz/Intern/guangjian/instagram?api=like, so from PHP we run the code below:

```
if($_GET['api'] == 'like'){

header('location:https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=3548d38f15b54dbfb744bf0705fa8198&redirect_uri=http://ewands.no-ip.biz/intern/guangjian/instagram?function=like&response_type=code');
```

The above will redirect the page to http://ewands.no-ip.biz/intern/guangjian/instagram/?function=like&code=3b50fdbcd0184f979b31f5b0d12354c4 <-- Instagram server added a random code, next, use curl to get the access token:

```
} 
if($_GET['function'] == 'like') {

    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
    $access_token_parameters = array(
        'client_id'                =>     '3548d38f15b54dbfb744bf0705fa8198',
        'client_secret'            =>     '97e12a30416d4436a52107d0d1820e91',
        'grant_type'               =>     'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri'             =>     'http://ewands.no-ip.biz/intern/guangjian/instagram?function=like', 
        'code'                     =>     $code
        );
    $curl = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);   
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);   
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    $result = curl_exec($curl);   
    curl_close($curl); 

    $arr = json_decode($result,true);
    $token = $arr['access_token'];
```

I have tested that I am able to get the token, so far so good, then the next part does not work, I am just trying my luck, since I am not familiar with curl and there are no tutorial out there from Googling for Instagram API tutorial.

```
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$media_id.'/likes';

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'access_token='.$token);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

}
```

Comment: Did you `print_r()` out `$result` (last snippet of your code)? it should give you an clear message or error on what's wrong!

Comment: @AdamAzad Yes, nothing is shown.

Comment: @JianShort whats the media_id you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Instagram returns a # in the token return which renders it useless for $_GET.
The token is only supposed to be used one.
You manually copy it from the URI and then use it accordingly in your code.

It is HIGHLY insecure.
You're over thinking it.